# Can logical operators be used with find and xargs?

Tags: bash, loops, find, xargs

I have a directory of about 5000 files of which some were erroneously written with a syntax error. I am using the following code to identify which files have the error:

```
ls -1 | while read a; do grep -q '^- ' $a || echo $a; done
```

I initially tried to use a combination of `find` and `xargs` but I couldn't figure out how to add the boolean logic I needed.

My use case is not I/O bound and completes fast enough. But I was curious to see if this same operation be done without relying on a bash loop. Although comfortable with Bash, I have a tendency to rely heavily on piping into loops which often leads to [mind numbingly slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218254/how-to-speed-up-this-log-parser).

Comment: What is that you want to achieve in the end? Display file names containing the string?

Comment: Display the files which do NOT match this regular expression. It's the boolean logical OR which is the sticking point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean logic with `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -exec grep -q '^- ' {} \; -o -print \)
```

The `-o` option is a logical OR. If the command executed by `-exec` will return a non-zero return value `-print` will print the filename.

Comment: Thank you; this works perfectly. I fiddled with it a bit and found that if I add `-mindepth 1` as well then it will avoid outputting the current folder (`.`) with the rest of the results.

Comment: Yes, however `-type f` should exclude the current folder `(.)` anyway.

Comment: Would you explain why the parenthesis are required to avoid the (`.`)?

Comment: Because `.` is a folder meaning `-type f` fails. That leads to `-print` being executed. You can read the line (without parentheses) as `-maxdepth 1 && -type f && -exec ... || -print`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You are welcome! It's a bit seldom used feature of `find` but *really* powerful.

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -L '^- ' {} +` would do, although in the spirit of the question perhaps it _is_ better to demonstrate the use of `\(…\)` and `-o`.
I do suggest adding `.` to make BSD `find` happy too, however. 
While not an option with the `\(…\)` and `-o` solution, note how in the alternate solution the use of `+` instead of `\;` makes the command much more efficient, because it (typically) results in only a _single_ `grep` call, rather than one for each filename.

Comment: What? They (mods) really removed two comments here. The discussion is now interrupted! Man, that's crazy! I'm really asking why! There was nothing, meaning 0, bad in that. @Zhro and I just discussed about the answer, which was faulty in the first place... I guess it was *too extensive*. I still can't believe it!

Comment: @hek2mgl: My apologies: I had flagged some of the comments as obsolete in an effort to streamline the thread, but I can now see how that was disruptive. Can I suggest adding the lost information (why `\(...\)` is needed for precedence so that the `-o -print` action doesn't unintentionally bypass the `-type f` test) directly to your answer, which is where it is more likely to get noticed anyway? (Doing so would then allow removing more comments.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this, using `grep -L`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -L '^- ' {} \;
```

The code above would list all files on the directory which do NOT contain a line starting with dash + space `-` in their contents.

To make the code above recursive (that is, to extend the search to all subdirectories), just remove the `-maxdepth 1` part out.

From `man grep` about option `-L`:

> -L, --files-without-match Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been
>   printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Use of `grep` alone is sufficient:

```
grep -d skip -L '^- ' *
```

<sup>Note: Unlike `find`, this will not automatically include *hidden* files.

To search *recursively*, use `grep -L '^- ' -R .` instead (although `-R` is not POSIX-compliant, it works with both GNU and BSD/macOS `grep`).</sup>

`-L`, as described in [Jamil Said's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685929/45375), prints the *path* (as specified) of each input file that does *not* contain the search term.

`-d skip` skips directories (while option `-d` is not POSIX-compliant, it is supported by both GNU and BSD/macOS `grep`).

---

*Caveat:* As [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) points out in a comment, **the command line that results after filename expansion of `*` *may* be too long**, resulting in an error such as `/usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long`.
(By contrast, if you make `grep` search recursively with `-R .`, you won't face this problem.)

The **max. length is platform-specific**, and can be queried with **`getconf ARG_MAX`**, though note that **the actual limit is *lower* than that, depending on the size of your environment** - see [this article](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

**In practice, 5000 files will likely not be a problem**, even on platforms with a relatively low max. length, such as macOS - unless you have exceptionally long filenames and/or your globbing pattern has a lengthy path component<sup>[1]</sup>
.
Recent Linux versions have a much higher limit.

**If you do hit the limit** and must work around it, **use `xargs`** as follows:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 grep -d skip -L '^- '
```

Note that while `-0` to read NUL-terminated input is not POSIX-compliant, it is supported by both GNU and BSD/macOS `xargs`.

If the input filenames indeed don't fit on a *single* command line, `xargs` will partition the input in a way that results in the fewest `grep` invocations necessary to process all of them.

---

<sup>[1] macOS 10.12 has a limit of `262,144` bytes (256 KB); if we conservatively assume that, after deducting the size of the environment and the fixed part of the command line, we get `250,000` bytes for our filename list, this gives us `250000 / 5000 == 50` bytes per filename + space (the list separator), so that each filename is allowed to be up to `49` bytes long.

By contrast, Ubuntu 16.04's limit is 8 x times higher: `2,097,152` bytes (2 MB).</sup>

Comment: The problem is the glob. As the OP says, there are 5000 files in that folder. That would give you an `argument list too long` error. You need to use `-r` (or `-R`)

Comment: @mklement0 Very good answer. +2 (which is unfortunately not allowed) I'm surprised that 5000 isn't a problem. I knew that the limit is configurable but I have underestimated it's (default) value.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Thank you. I've added a calculation as a footnote. It looks like on modern platforms such as Linux and macOS you'd have to recompile the kernel to increase the `ARG_MAX` limit, according to http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/